# why ASCII 0x80 ~ 0x9F cannot be displayed by browser?

Tags: browser, encode

```
> console.log("abc\xb2")  //abc² 
abc² 
> console.log("abc\x80")  //abc€
abc
```

I tested it in chrome 34 and IE 11. Any ideas ?

Comment: By definition, ASCII ends with 0x7F. All above is not ASCII anymore.

Comment: JavaScript always uses UTF-8. `console.log("abc\u20ac")` will give you `abc€` … and so will `console.log("abc€")` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Character '€' was \x80 in Windows-1252, but \xE2\x82\xAC in utf-8. I made a mistake by saving the file in Windows-1252.

this string was sent to browser by websocket and browser thought it was in utf-8. So I didn't get '€' since \x80 is an unprintable character in utf-8.